# What is the difference between ViewPropertyAnimator's translateYBy() vs yBy() methods?

Tags: android, animation

ViewPropertyAnimators (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html) have two types of methods to move Views around:

translateX() vs x(), translateY() vs y(), translateXBy() vs xBy() and finally translateYBy() vs yBy().

Can someone tell me the difference between these methods?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The documentation states that `X` and `Y` properties are absolute positions, while `translationX` and `translationY` are referred to the LEFT and TOP properties respectively.

So, the difference between `animate().x()` and `animate().translationX()` is that one animates to an absolute value, while the other animates to a still absolute value but determined by the view `LEFT` and `TOP` values.

By contrast, `animate().xBy()` and `animate().translationXBy()` increase (algebraically) the property value by the specified amount.

That is the origin of the "some mathematics" cited above.

Comment: I did not get. can you please give more info. or link to some resources. so that i can understand the concept

Answer (score 38):

A visualization of [translationY()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html#translationY(float)), [y()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html#y(float)), [yBy()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html#yBy(float)), [translationYBy()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html#translationYBy(float)) methods are bellow

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: It took some time to focus on these gifs "especially which button is being clicked" on which gif, but now I won't get confused in these ever. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for pointing me out. I added highlighter and a click counter

Comment: What's the difference between YBY and TRANSLATIONYBY?

Comment: `ViewPropertyAnimator.getValue` for `TRANSLATIONYBY` returns `node.getTranslationY()`, `ViewPropertyAnimator.getValue` for `YBY ` returns `mView.mTop + node.getTranslationY()` as a result `ViewPropertyAnimator.setValue()` pass the same value

Answer (score 6):

`x` refers to the current visual position of a view in the x-axis. So, for example, when you animate `x` by calling `view.animate().x(10)`, the view will be animated such that it moves to `x=10`. Let's just assume that view was in a position of (100, 150) when you started the animation. By the end of the animation, the view will be in (10, 150).

Now, contrast this with `translationX`. If you animate this property by calling `view.animate().translationX(10)`, you are moving a view by that many pixels in the x-axis. Let's assume the same example, where the view was in a position of (100, 150) when you started the animation. By the end of the animation, the view will be in (110, 150).

Hope that clarifies the difference between `x()` and `translationX()`. The difference is the same for `y()` and `translationY()`, but in the y-axis.

In my view, `xBy()` achieves the same effect as `translationX()` but by using the `x` property itself plus some mathematics. `yBy()` and `translationY()` are the equivalents in the y-axis.

Hope that clarifies...

Comment: Thanks, I always wondered why they needed a translateXBy method. It feels exactly the same as XBy.

Comment: This is the wrong answer. See Nicolò Parolini's answer

Answer (score 0):

> translationX and translationY: These properties control where the View is located as a delta from its left and top coordinates which are set by its layout container.
>
> x and y: These are simple utility properties to describe the final
>   location of the View in its container, as a sum of the left and top
>   values and translationX and translationY values.

[Animate views docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to understand the difference between the
**x** vs **translationX** properties of a view.

You can do so by referring the article over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44434383/understanding-view-settranslationy-x)

After that you will get the difference.

1. **x** is the absolute position from layout. (**position** + **translationX**)
2. the **translationX** is an offset that is applied to the position of the View

When we animate using **x() / translationX() / xBy() / translationXby()** property the views **translationX** property of the view is changed. You can also check it by adding logs like below

```
Log.i("INFO getX", String.valueOf(bartImageView.getX()));
Log.i("INFO getTranslationX", String.valueOf(bartImageView.getTranslationX()));
```

Below how they look before and after the end of animations from various functions:

**Before** (Same before all animations):

```
 INFO getX: 278.0
 INFO getTranslationX: 0.0
```

1. **x(100)**

   After (1st Time):

   ```
    INFO getX: 100.0
    INFO getTranslationX: -178.0
   ```

   After (2nd Time)(**Doesn't Animate**):

   ```
    INFO getX: 100.0
    INFO getTranslationX: -178.0
   ```
2. **translationX(100):**

   After (1st time):

   ```
     INFO getX: 378.0
     INFO getTranslationX: 100
   ```

   After (2nd Time)(**Doesn't Animate**):

   ```
     INFO getX: 378.0
     INFO getTranslationX: 100
   ```
3. **xBy(100):**

   After (1st Time):

   ```
     INFO getX: 378.0
     INFO getTranslationX: 100
   ```

   After (2nd Time):

   ```
     INFO getX: 478.0
     INFO getTranslationX: 200
   ```
4. **translationXBy(100)**

   After (1st Time):

   ```
     INFO getX: 378.0
     INFO getTranslationX: 100
   ```

   After (2nd Time):

   ```
     INFO getX: 478.0
     INFO getTranslationX: 200
   ```

As you can see **xBy()** and **translationXBy()** work the same way and keeping adding **translationX** to the view algebraically every time animation is triggered.

Same thing works for **y Dimension** as well. Feel free to add logs and check out.