# understanding View.setTranslationY() [ /X() ]

Tags: android, user-interface

as the title says i want to understand what that method exactly is doing.

firstable i have double checked that the coordinate system of android works like that: 
[coordinate system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWyGr.png)

secondary - please take a minute to check my android studio screen, and the method quick doc. why is that value of my view (after clicking it) is 106? 
[android screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LY0IX.png)

Comment: The TranslationY is relative to the Y-position

Comment: This means that the final position after the translation is 106 + 10

Answer (score 14, accepted):

the coordinate system is correct.

`getY()` will return the value of the top of your `View` + the Y translation. so, if `getY()` is returning 106 and you set translation y to 10, the top of your view should be at 96. try calling also `getTop()` and check what is that value

the translation is an offset that is applied to the position of the `View`. if the layout place your `View` at `x;y` and you call `setTranslationY(10)`, your `View` will appear at `x;y+10`. it's a way to control the positioning of the `View` after the layout

bonus tip, instead of logging everything, use the debugger

in case you still have doubts about the difference between the position and translation, you could try this, create an empty activity and set this layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.lelloman.dummy.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="asd asd"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="asd"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

then, you will see that the `TextView` is right above the `Button`, because this is how the `RelativeLayout` will position the `View`s given these layout parameters. now, try to call

```
findViewById(R.id.button).setTranslationY(100);
```

you will notice that the button will be moved down by 100px, but the `TextView` will still be at the old position, because the translation is applied after the layout. it is something specific to that `View` that is not taken into account for the positioning of the `View` within its parent

you could also set the translation in the xml with

```
<Button
    android:translationY="100px"
    ...
```

Comment: could you define what is the translation?

Comment: answer updated, if you have more doubts feel free to ask

Comment: firstable, thank you for your answer i really appreciate it. 
secondary i'm not sure you are right.

Comment: sorry, my explanation was mistakenly deleted.

please check my android screen again:
the coordinate of title View is (0,0). and if ill relate to your answer ("your View will appear at x;y+10") after setting 'title.setTranslationY(10)' his new coordinates should be (0,10) - but its not. at the monitor you could see its Y is 106px.

Comment: ok so, 1, if you want to include code in your question please do not use images, just copy the code. 2, you might want to ask yourself, what setX and setY actually do? well, they will set the translation to be x-left and y-top respectively. 3, if you want to learn about positioning views, forget about setX, setY, setTranslationX and setTranslationY, these methods chage only the rendering position of the view, not its actual place within the container