# Difference between setTranslationY() and translationYBy()?

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I am trying to achieve the following functionality :-
When Someone taps on my image view it should show the image appearing with an animation i.e. entering from screen top. To get this I am following the following approach

- Translate the image view out of view
- Attach the image to view
- Translate it back with animation

I have two set of codes where animating the  view out of screen does not work but just calling setTranslationY() on view works
Refer to code segment attached

```
imageView.setTranslationY(-2000);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);
imageView.animate().translationYBy(2000).setDuration(300);
```

This works but following doesn't.

```
imageView.animate().translationYBy(-2000);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);
imageView.animate().translationYBy(2000).setDuration(300);
```

Can you please explain about the behaviour and maybe difference between setTranslateY() vs translationYby().

Comment: I think it should be - 2000  in first line of second code snippet

Comment: @VaibhavJani Edited , Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator

> translationY
>
> Added in API level 12
>   public ViewPropertyAnimator translationY (float value)
>   This method will cause the View's translationY property to be animated to the specified value. Animations already running on the property will be canceled.
>
> Parameters value  float: The value to be animated to.

---

> translationYBy
>
> Added in API level 12 public ViewPropertyAnimator
>   translationYBy (float value) This method will cause the View's
>   translationY property to be animated by the specified value.
>   Animations already running on the property will be canceled.
>
> Parameters value  float: The amount to be animated by, as an offset
>   from the current value.

Clearly the difference is on the meaning of the parameter: for translationY it represents an absolute position, for translationYBy it represents on offset from the current value.

Comment: So if u set translationYBy(100) it would move the current position from 360 to 460 and remane at position 460?

Comment: that's what documentation says.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between translationYBy and setTranslationY is that the first one will affect the animation of the image when you click on it while the the second one will affect the image as soon as the program has start running, meaning if you position the image lets say 360 by using `setTranslationY`, it will be at 360 in the beginning of the app

Answer (score 0):

**Android setTranslationY vs translationYBy**

- setTranslationY moved on  point one single time
- translationYBy moved on  point every time

[[Take a look at example]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50190859/4770877)