# What is the difference between setX(), x() and setTranslationX() in Android of ViewPropertyAnimater class

Tags: android, animation

I was already confused by setX() and setTranslationX() methods from ViewPropertyAnimater class because they both moved the view in the exact same manner. And then I came across x() method.

*(This is my first question on Stack Overflow. So, if the question has insufficient information then please let me know somehow. Glad to know some tips on how to ask a good question)*

**Please at least show an actual situation where setX() and where setTranslationX () are used. Just for clarification**

Can someone please explain me clearly what these methods do specifically. With an example if possible.

Answer (score 0):

`setX()` does as the expected, sets the X of the view.

`setTranslationX()` doesn't actually set the X of the view, but rather makes a margin-like push to the view. But the view's X stays where it is.

`x()` is probably a more like xBy().

Check [What is the difference between ViewPropertyAnimator's translateYBy() vs yBy() methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23352789/what-is-the-difference-between-viewpropertyanimators-translateyby-vs-yby-me)

Comment: Thanks. I got everything. But still have some confusions over the actual use of setTranslationX () method. Can you please tell me a situation where setTranslationX () should be used rather than setX() method?

Comment: TranslationX is mostly used as a percentage. For example, pushing your view 50% on the X axis instead of calculating the X. I believe the percentage values can be sent in XML animation and layouts, not sure if it can be used in code

Answer (score 0):

Some real situation you can find in open source project(for example github.com) but if you know how it works it brings more effect and you can youse it where you need it

and the visual difference you can find [[here]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50190859/4770877)